# Runtime Error in 4Sum tried with optimised code

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

In this question, we're given an array and a target integer value, so we need to return the unique quadruplets of four elements having a sum equal to the target.

So, I've tested with multiple testcases and it ran correctly but there is this one testcase which is throwing me an error of runtime error when submitted on leetcode.

Testcase:

4

0 0 0 0

1

The output should be an empty array, but I've ran the code with the same testcase on my machine as well as on an online compiler giving the correct output, i.e. empty vector.

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std ;

vector<vector<int>> four_sum(vector<int> &nums, int target)
{
    // sorting the vector
    sort(nums.begin(),nums.end()) ;
    int len = nums.size() ;

    if (len < 4)
    {
        return {} ;
    }

    cout<<"Sorted Array is: "<<endl ;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        cout<<nums[i]<<" " ;
    }

    cout<<endl ;

    vector<int> temp ;
    vector<vector<int>> ans ;
    int sum = 0, curr_sum = 0 ;
    int i = 0, j = len-1 ;

    // a + b + c + d = target
    while (i < j)
    {
        if (i == 0 or j == len or (i > 0 and nums[i] != nums[i-1]) or (j < len and nums[j] != nums[j+1]))
        {
            sum = nums[i] + nums[j] ;
            int lo = i + 1, hi = j - 1 ;

            while (lo < hi)
            {
                if (nums[lo] + nums[hi] + sum == target)
                {
                    temp.push_back(nums[i]) ;
                    temp.push_back(nums[lo]) ;
                    temp.push_back(nums[hi]) ;
                    temp.push_back(nums[j]) ;

                    ans.push_back(temp) ;

                    temp.clear() ;

                    curr_sum = target ;

                    while (lo < hi and nums[lo] == nums[lo + 1])
                    {
                        lo++ ;
                    }

                    while (lo < hi and nums[hi] == nums[hi - 1])
                    {
                        hi-- ;
                    }

                    lo++ ;
                    hi-- ;
                }

                else if (sum + nums[lo] + nums[hi] < target)
                {
                    curr_sum = sum + nums[lo] + nums[hi] ;
                    lo++ ;
                }

                else
                {
                    curr_sum = sum + nums[lo] + nums[hi] ;
                    hi-- ;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (curr_sum < target)
        {
            i++ ;
        }

        else if (curr_sum == target)
        {
            i++ ;
            j-- ;
        }
        
        else
        {
            j-- ;
        }
    }

    return ans ;
}

int main()
{
    int n, x ;
    cin>>n ;

    vector<int> nums ;

    while (n--)
    {
        cin>>x ;
        nums.push_back(x) ;
    }

    int target ;
    cin>>target ;

    vector<vector<int>> ans = four_sum(nums,target) ;

    cout<<"Ans: "<<endl ;
    for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ans[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout<<ans[i][j]<<" " ;
        }
        cout<<endl ;
    }
    
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: If you know the test case, there is no need for `cin` statements in the code you posted.  Just initialize the vector with those test values.  Also, do not tag `dsa` -- It does *not* mean "Data Structures and Algorithms" (did you read the tag information)?

Comment: *but I've ran the code with the same testcase on my machine as well as on an online compiler giving the correct output* -- Instead of using `[]` to access the elements of the vector, use `at()`.  You should then see that your code will fail to work on all of the compilers you are testing on, due to you going out-of-bounds of the vector.

Comment: `j == len` is a mysterious condition; `j` starts at `len-1` and is only decremented so it can't be true.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution to your 4 sum problem, but this is the cause of the problem, given the test data you say is working:

This line:

```
if (i == 0 or j == len or (i > 0 and nums[i] != nums[i-1]) or (j < len and nums[j] != nums[j+1]))
```

has an out-of-bounds access due to `j + 1` being equal to 4, and `nums` is a vector that has a `size()` equal to 4.

Using `at()` instead of `[]` to access the elements shows this to be the case:

```
if (i == 0 or j == len or (i > 0 and nums[i] != nums[i-1]) or (j < len and nums[j] != nums.at(j+1)))
```

This throws an `std::out_of_range` exception.  Given this change, your program with that test case should fail all the compilers you claimed had a "working" program.

Accessing an item in a vector using `[]` that is out-of-bounds results in *undefined behavior*.  This means anything can happen, including seeming to "work" correctly.

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/abq7vWah4).